# Expose container on random port on internal IP

Tags: docker

I'd like to be able to run a container with the `-P` parameter while having it bind to the internal 10.10.0.0/22 subnet.

By default once do something like this:

```
docker run -d -P --name=nginx nginx
```

It will look something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
dbb556c99c81        nginx         "/usr/sbin/nginx"        2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp        nginx
```

Exposing it on 0.0.0.0/0 Is there a way to make this my internal IP?

Comment: What do you mean your internal IP? The `0.0.0.0` is the docker interface. And you can access port `32773` on the internal IP of the host machine's interface

Comment: Well I specifically didn't want that. Just keeping it internal without having to do firewall rules and not expose it to the outside world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually bind to a specific interface when selecting individual ports with `-p`, e.g.:

```
$ docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80/tcp --name test-nginx nginx
2e07ebc61bcdc82a187a27eabca10211a4c9ac09d66e516e5c176d7282cffe2b

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
2e07ebc61bcd        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:8080->80/tcp   test-nginx
```

With `-P`, it uses the interface configured on the daemon (`dockerd` or `docker daemon`). By default that is 0.0.0.0, but you can change it to any other IP:

```
$ dockerd --help
# ...
--ip=0.0.0.0             Default IP when binding container ports
```

Note that 0.0.0.0 is listening on all interfaces, so the only reason to specify a specific IP is to lock down the container further, not to open it up for your environment.

Comment: Which is exactly what I needed! I want the container to not be available to the outside world while still using random ports.